# Django Rest Framework Return 403 in Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I return a different error code with django rest framework's serializers?

I have in my `serializer.py` file:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if 'Message' not in validated_data:
            # If message is blank, don't create the message
            return PermissionDenied()
```

But when I do that, it just returns `201` with the body `{"deleted":null}` instead of returning a `403` error.

How can I make it return the `403` error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `validate_message` method as follow:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_message(self, message):
    if not message:
        raise ValidationError('error message here')
    return message
```

Note that the ValidationError will return a `400 Bad Request` status code which is better for when a required field is missing from the `POST` data

Answer (score 4):

[@Marcell Erasmus's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5968226/marcell-erasmus) answer is nice, but it's not covered the status code part (how to return a `HTTP 403 status code`)
First, you need to add a ***Custom exception class*** as below,

```
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework import status


class CustomAPIException(exceptions.APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
    default_code = 'error'

    def __init__(self, detail, status_code=None):
        self.detail = detail
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
```

and use the class **wherever you want** by ,

```
if some_condition:
    raise CustomAPIException({"some": "data"})
```

One of the most advantage of this particular class is that you could raise API exception with custom status codes by specifying the **`status_code`** parameter
**Ex.**

```
if some_condition:
    raise CustomAPIException({"some": "data"},status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
```

Comment: Actually DRF's exceptions automatically return the appropriate status code.

Comment: Here its return 403 status code by default. You could change that if you want....( Customization, what I meant)